# How to get all id_attachment with one loop?

Tags: media, gallery

I have some lines of code which shows the url of my wordpress image gallery by means of an id, but I need it not to have to be selected by me, if not that every time an image is added, it is not necessary to write the id in the code.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id = 7 );
if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
  <div class="element-item marketing imagePost">
     <a class="popup-with-move-anim" href="#project-2"><div class="element-item-overlay"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></div>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" />
  </div>
<?php endif; 

endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: It always helps if you include some code.

Comment: that's the code i'm using. What it does is take an image from the wordpress gallery by the id

Comment: Well where else is the function supposed to get that information?  I think the logic here is headed in the wrong direction.  Can you explain what this code is attempting to do?  I understand it's getting an image from an image gallery, but why?  When?  How?

Comment: The information comes from the the_post () property, which is a column in the wordpress database.
And with
wp_get_attachment_image_src ($ attachment_id = 7);
Gets the id of the image I want I feel this $ attachment_id = 7 the variable that sends to query

Comment: What relationship does attachment 7 have to the post? Is it the post thumbnail? If you want it to be dynamic is has to come from somewhere.

Comment: Joel, I understand where that's saved in the DB, what I'm asking is 'where in your code are you expecting to obtain it'?  How is it related to the post?  You said it's a gallery image, so it's not the Featured Image then?  When the page loads, if you don't want to manually input this, where SHOULD the page be expecting to get the information?  Everything is stored in the database, but the page needs to know 'which' item from the database it's supposed to get.  That's the part we're all unclear on.